# textemdash doesn't render in biblatex with moderncv

Tags: biblatex, moderncv

I am trying to include a bibliography (with `biblatex`) in a CV (with `moderncv`). However, when I include a `\textemdash{}` in a field of a bibliography entry, it renders as a space instead of an em dash. This behavior doesn't happen when I switch to `\documentclass{article}`, nor does it happen with `\textemdash{}` outside of a bibliography entry, nor does it happen with `---` instead of `\textemdash{}`. Following is an MWE.

`main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,colorlinks,linkcolor=true]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}
    \makecvtitle
    
    \nocite{*}
    
    The following should render as ``Hello \textemdash{} World!'':
    
    \printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

`mybib.bib`:

```
@misc{helloworld,
    title = {Hello \textemdash{} World!},
    author = {Doe, John},
    date = {2021-08},
}
```

Renders as:
[image]

Comment: Can't you type it directly from the keyboard?

Comment: I ran your example unchanged in texlive2021 and got [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etv60.png)

Comment: I can't reproduce: the very same input typesets with the dash.

Comment: @Bernard: I could, but I am using output bibfiles generated by Better BibLaTex from Zotero, which automatically encodes Unicode em dashes as `\textemdash`. I would rather not disable this feature there, since I need it for other use cases.

@DavidCarlisle and @egreg, I am running it in `xelatex` from `texlive2020` but sounds like I may have a software version issue. I will experiment more and keep updated.

Comment: Update: The `\textemdash{}` appears correctly after updating to `texlive2021`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Biber recodes the `\textemdash` in your title to `—`.

The example compiles fine with a current version of LaTeX and XeLaTeX, but I could reproduce an issue with the XeLaTeX in Overleaf's TeX Live 2020 (https://www.overleaf.com/read/rggbprxmtthn). There the problem could be fixed by loading `\usepackage{fontspec}`, which is probably not that bad an idea if you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX anyway.

With `\usepackage{fontspec}` https://www.overleaf.com/read/zhyqysgwfynf, i.e.

```
\documentclass[11pt,colorlinks,linkcolor=true]{moderncv}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
sorting=ydnt]{biblatex}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{helloworld,
    title = {Hello \textemdash{} World!},
    author = {Doe, John},
    date = {2021-08},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \makecvtitle
  \nocite{*}

  The following should render as ``Hello \textemdash{} World!'':

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

shows

[image: John Doe. Hello — World! Aug. 2021.]

as expected.